# GoldenGate version 12 installation/upgradation on zOS

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I have GoldenGate version 11.1 on my z/OS and Linux servers. I need to upgrade the GoldenGate to version 12 on both the servers. The database that GG is interacting is DB2. I looked up on the internet for the instructions but to me they seem little complex.
My question is if it is possible for a standard GoldenGate developer to install/upgrade its version on both the servers or I will need a consultant from Oracle to do this activity for me? The good part of calling a Oracle consultant is I will get a lot of learning but the con is they charge a lot for this activity.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading a replication system is not a straightforward task. As you have mentioned, there are many thing you need to be aware of. You need first to plan the upgrade process, test it and as a final task, implement it on the production replication system.

For example, GoldenGate 12 has different default values for some parameters than GoldenGate 11. You might need to check the PRM files and adapt them to the never version.

Everything about the upgrade process is written in the documentation and in the Oracle MOS notes. It is possible that all the work that is done during the upgrade is made by a mortal person.

You have to choose by yourself what level of risk you are willing to accept. And make a plan what to do if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading can be a complex task and time consuming.  The product team for Oracle GoldenGate is attempting to make it as easy and painless as possible.

Seeing that you are on Oracle GoldenGate 11g for Non-Oracle (DB2 for z/OS), the upgrade process can be a bit perplexing.

First, I would recommend you skip 12c and go to 19c.  Oracle GoldenGate 19c has all the patches and fixes that 12c does not.

Second, the 12c/19c set of binaries for GoldenGate for Non-Oracle (DB2 for z/OS) is a different install.  Starting in Oracle GoldenGate 12c for Non-Oracle (DB2 for z/OS) you can do the install on a Linux mid-tier machine.  The only thing that gets installed on the z/OS platform is two (2) stored procedures.  This approach opens up a lot of flexibility for the z/OS platform and lowers the overall MIPS processes.  More information can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/gghdb/using-oracle-goldengate-db2-z-os.html

Upgrading the system would be the similar to what you have done in the past, but now it will be all linux based and provide you a cost savings by lowing MIPS.